# Can we say anything about the minimum of a perspective function compared to that of the original function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given convex function $f(x)$, its perspective function is $g(x,t) = tf(x/t), t>0$ is also convex. Is the minimum of $g$ over $(x,t)$ always less than (or larger than) the minimum of $f(x)$? Note that $x \in \mathbb{R}^n, t \in \mathbb{R}^1$.

Comment: Is the minimum for some fixed $t$, or is the minimum taken over all $(x,t)$?

Comment: I assume the domain for $x$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$? Or, can it be restricted to a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the minimum of the perspective is always less than or equal to the minimum of the original function. Suppose $x^*$ is a minimizer of $f$, then
$$
\min_x f(x) = f(x^*) = g(x^*,1) \ge \min_{x,t} g(x,t)
$$

Comment: Oh, yes. This should have been obvious